# Swift - Write an Array to a Text File

Tags: arrays, file, text, swift, output

I read into myArray (native Swift) from a file containing a few thousand lines of plain text..

```
myData = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(myPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
var myArray = myData.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

I change some of the text in myArray (no point pasting any of this code).

Now I want to write the updated contents of myArray to a new file.
I've tried this ..

```
let myArray2 = myArray as NSArray
myArray2.writeToFile(myPath, atomically: false)
```

but the file content is then in the plist format.

Is there any way to write an array of text strings to a file (or loop through an array and append each array item to a file) in Swift (or bridged Swift)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reduce your array back down to a string:

```
var output = reduce(array, "") { (existing, toAppend) in
    if existing.isEmpty {
        return toAppend
    }
    else {
        return "\(existing)\n\(toAppend)"
    }
}
output.writeToFile(...)
```

The `reduce` method takes a collection and merges it all into a single instance. It takes an initial instance and closure to merge all elements of the collection into that original instance.

My example takes an empty string as its initial instance. The closure then checks if the existing output is empty. If it is, it only has to return the text to append, otherwise, it uses [String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_420) to return the existing output and the new element with a newline in between.

Using various syntactic sugar features from Swift, the whole reduction can be reduced to:

```
var output = reduce(array, "") { $0.isEmpty ? $1 : "\($0)\n\($1)" }
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex and performs concatenation for each adjacent two-element pair. How about just:

`let pieces = [ "hello", "goodbye" ]`
`let joined = "\n".join(pieces)`

Comment: @DPlusV, if you have an alternative solution, please post it as a separate answer. Also, downvotes should be used "whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." I may be mistaken, but I don't believe my answer fits into that category. If it does, please specify why.

Comment: With all due respect, your answer is technically correct, but is the wrong tool for the job. To give an example, just because one can compute Fibonacci terms recursively, it doesn't mean one should. SO is used as a learning vector by many users. It's better to advocate good practices. Some of this code ends up in production software that me and you will use. The negative is not a personal attack, but more of a warning to someone "hey, don't just copy-and-paste this code."

Comment: @DPlusV, I don't take it personally. Negative votes are for incorrect or misleading information, otherwise separate answers can compete for the most votes based on being the best answer for the question. The more important part of my comment is that you should provide your answer separately so that it can be featured more prominently. I will vote it up myself. (I agree that your answer is better, but I still feel my answer has value to show creative use of `reduce`)

Comment: Great idea, and thanks for being a constructive SO'er!

Answer (score 23):

As drewag points out in the accepted post, you can build a string from the array and then use the `writeToFile` method on the string.

However, you can simply use Swift's `Array.joinWithSeparator` to accomplish the same with less code and likely better performance.

For example:

```
// swift 2.0
let array = [ "hello", "goodbye" ]
let joined = array.joinWithSeparator("\n")
do {
    try joined.writeToFile(saveToPath, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} catch {
    // handle error
}

// swift 1.x
let array = [ "hello", "goodbye" ]
let joined = "\n".join(array)
joined.writeToFile(...)
```

Comment: ah something close to perl/javascript.  it's short and sweet, i like it.  if i could vote this up a 100X, i would.

Comment: It changed, in Swift 5 it's: `array.joined(separator: "\n")`.

Answer (score 4):

With **Swift 5** and I guess with **Swift 4** you can use code snippet which works fine to me.

```
let array = ["hello", "world"]
let joinedStrings = array.joined(separator: "\n")

do {
    try joinedStrings.write(toFile: outputURL.path, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
} catch let error {
    // handle error
    print("Error on writing strings to file: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift offers numerous ways to loop through an array. You can loop through the strings and print to a text file one by one. Something like so:

```
for theString in myArray {
    theString.writeToFile(myPath, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. It write only the last line.

Comment: @ricardopereira I think it's writing all the elements of the array. The problem, if you are following the example exactly as shown, is `myPath` is the same for each iteration. Each iteration is overwriting the file along with the contents of the previous iteration. Regardless, even if you update `myPath` each time, this is a bit of an awkward approach. If the array had 500 elements you'd need to have 500 files to store it this way. Have a look at the answer from @DPlusV.