# How to store an Array of selected rows?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

In my code I have a table view that loads the name of users using my app. When a user selects a row it will appear a checkmark. What I want to do is save an array that contains all the selected rows (the array will contain the names). I found some information, but I still learning iOS programming and I dont know Obj-c.

This is what I have done so far:

```
var selectedMembers = [String]?
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.names?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UserCell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = names![indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    selectedMembers = Array()
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {

        if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark
        {
            cell.accessoryType = .None

            self.selectedMembers?.remove(indexPath)

        }
        else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        self.selectedMembers?.append(indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift - Write an Array to a Text File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977139/swift-write-an-array-to-a-text-file)

Comment: Just check this Question, is about how to save an Swift Array to a file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977139/swift-write-an-array-to-a-text-file

Comment: Is your question how to save the array for later use or how to get the names of the selected members (The string from the row)

Comment: @milo526 I will use these names (saved in the array) to create a group.

Answer (score 2):

To get the names you will need to use the selected row and get the entry of that row into your array with names.

To get the row of a `indexpath` you can use

```
indexPath.row
```

To get the name of your member you would use

```
names![indexPath.row-1]
```

Ofcourse you would save this to your array using

```
self.selectedMembers?.append(names![indexPath.row-1])
```

to remove the item you will need to add an extra step

```
self.selectedMembers?.removeAtIndex(selectedMembers.indexOf(names![indexPath.row-1]))
```

Comment: Using this solution I got the message: "fatal error: Array index out of range." I deleted the "-1" and I got in my array just the name of the last member selected.

Comment: Could you please specify as to what line returned the error?

Comment: This line:  
self.selectedMembers?.append(names![indexPath.row-1]). The app crashes when I select the row.

Comment: In your interface builder did you enable the possibility to select multiple rows (Do you see multiple checkmarks)

Comment: Yes, the checkmaks appears in all selected users.

Comment: But at any given moment there is only 1 entry in your selectedMembers array?

Comment: When I deleted the "-1" I could select the names without crash the app. I did a print of selectedMembers and shows only the last name(row) that I selected on my table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and didDeselectRowAtIndexPath delegate methods like so to keep track of the index paths in the table.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let index = find(selectedIndexPaths, indexPath) {
        selectedIndexPaths.removeAtIndex(index)
    }

}
```

Then you can backtrack and get the selected objects using the index paths.

Comment: It gives me the message: "Cannot Invoke "append" with an argument list of type '(NSIndexPath)'." at the line  selectedMembers.append(indexPath)

Comment: Make sure you intialize it like this `var selectedIndexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()`

Comment: hey what's find(selectedIndexPaths,indexPath)? m getting error use of unresolve identifier 'find'.